# How to discard changes using repo

Tags: reset

`repo status` shows me a lot of un-wanted changes.

It would be duplicated if I enter every project and use `git reset --hard`.

Is there a way to reset all the changes using repo, something like `repo reset --hard`?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is the command I use for this kind of things, very useful

```
repo forall -vc "git reset --hard"
```

**What everything mean here ?**

the `repo forall` will execute for all repos.

the -`v` is verbose, so it will print the output of the command

the `-c "COMMAND TO EXECUTE"` is the actual command you want

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just to add, if you want to suppress the output, omitting the -v argument didn't work for me, it still printed the output. I had to add `&>/dev/null` to suppress the output.

Comment: `-v` does not appear to be needed anymore as of v1.12.37.

Comment: `repo forall -c 'git reset --hard ; git clean -fdx'`  is better as `git reset --hard` will not remove untracked files, where as `git clean -fdx` will remove any files from the tracked root directory that are not under Git tracking along with any ignored files.

Comment: Working on some strange repo with gits placed one below the other, I found that the repo forall processes the tree bottom-up. for such screwed up repos that fails. Can check order with  `repo forall -c "pwd"`

Answer (score 34):

If there is a need to revert working folder to the **clean** state where you don't have local modifications and no untracked files (i.e. where **repo status** shows nothing), I found these two approaches useful on [repo sync and deleted/modified files](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/QIne5MVjO7U)

```
repo forall -c 'git reset --hard ; git clean -fdx'
```

or

```
rm -rf * ; repo sync -l
// note that .repo is preserved after that
```

Note, that this is not equivalent to initializing a new local repo and syncing (e.g. stash is preserved)

If you are not sure what is going on, please read the full thread [repo sync and deleted/modified files](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/QIne5MVjO7U)

Comment: Cool, I like this method:   fast and clean, exactly like "rm -rf *; git checkout -f" provided the ".git" exists.

Comment: I think it will not remove the committed changes in local repository (will remove only the changes in the working directory and staging area) which can lead to conflicts if it is followed by repo sync on a newer version for example. `git reset --hard origin` might remove local commits. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I tried `rm -rf * ; repo sync -l` on my local workspace and it removed the local commits in my projects. So, I think it is a very good way to reset your workspace and make a fresh build.

Comment: What would be the command to have multiple threads with `repo sync -l`. Will it make it faster?

Answer (score 17):

The working command is :

```
repo forall -vc "git reset --hard"
```

**The command and options description**

- forall

> Executes the given shell command in each project

**Options (that can be used with the `forall` command)**

> `-c`: command and arguments to execute. The command is evaluated through /bin/sh and any arguments after it are passed through as shell
> positional parameters.
>
> `-p`: show project headers before output of the specified command. This is achieved by binding pipes to the command's stdin, stdout, and
> sterr streams, and piping all output into a continuous stream that is
> displayed in a single pager session.
>
> `-v`: show messages the command writes to stderr.

For more information please refer the [repo document](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo)

Comment: `repo sync -d` did not work for me.  `repo status` still showed all my unwanted changes.

Comment: Actually you should have made this another answer. Will confuse people this way

Answer (score 9):

I use the repo forall command with the below syntax and it helps me to reset the tracking files.

```
repo forall -p -c 'git checkout -f foo'
```

where `foo` should be replaced with a legitimate branch name.

Answer (score 7):

repo forall does not cover all of the git tree

```
#!/bin/bash
for gitdir in $(find . -type d -name .git -prune); do
    pushd $(dirname $gitdir)
    git reset --hard
    popd
done
```

Comment: repo forall as in rans comment

Comment: Sometimes in my working copy, `repo forall` doesn't cover all the git tree. This  approach work greatly.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to use this command as `repo forall` didn't seem to fix every git repo.

Comment: I'd add `-type d` and `-prune` to `find` command to not descend into repo dirs once `.git` dir is found.